# How to properly subscribe to Uniswap v3 pool price events with NodeJS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, uniswap, websocket

In reviewing the Uniswap v3 Quoter documentation:

> These functions are not marked view because they rely on calling
> non-view functions and reverting to compute the result. They are also
> not gas efficient and should not be called on-chain.

I get that these functions are not efficient to use in your calls, yet I see a few examples using this function, like in [this example](https://github.com/jamesbachini/Uniswap-V3-Experiments/blob/main/uniswap-v3-trader-prtk418.js).

```
// Uniswap V3 Router Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6#code
const UNISWAP_QUOTER_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_factory","type":"address"},...........';
var uniswapRouter = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_QUOTER_ABI, UNISWAP_QUOTER_ADDRESS);
let uniswapResult = await uniswapRouter.methods.quoteExactInputSingle(inputTokenAddress, outputTokenAddress, 3000, inputAmount, 0).call();  // <----
```

> `quoteExactInputSingle()`:  Returns the amount out received for a
> given exact input but for a swap of a single pool

Rather than polling the pool contract for price updates, I would like a an event I can subscribe to via WebSocket that provides this data.  As I'm new to this, it looks like I have to create a pair factory, correct?  Then what?